# Quartz failure in notifyJobStoreJobComplete method

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

#### Scenario:

1. We have a scheduler which is using JDBC Job Store. Quartz version is 2.1.2.
2. The job which is being scheduling is also updating a database.
3. The database is same for both quartz and the job itself and is hosted in MySQL Server. Both application tables and quartz tables are stored in the same database.
4. Connection pool is different for both application and quartz. In the application we are using spring for connection pooling and quartz is forced to use connection pooling via quartz.properties.
   Here is the snippet of quartz.properties

   ```
   org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true
   org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user = dbuser
   org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password =dbpassword
   org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections = 30
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.validationQuery = select 1
   #org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=21600000
   #org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
   #org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.numTestsPerEviction=-1
   #org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.testWhileIdle=true
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=true
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=120
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.initialPoolSize=5
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.minPoolSize=5
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.maxPoolSize=30
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.acquireIncrement=5
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.maxIdleTime=120
   org.quartz.datasource.qzDS.validateOnCheckout=true
   ```
5. Database is clustered with MASTER-MASTER replication on two servers and they are being used via virtual IP everywhere in the application and quartz.
6. Scheduler i.e. quartz is also clustered on the same two machines where MySQL is clustered.

#### The problem:

One of the servers (till now we have got the problem with backup server machine) is occasionally throwing database connection error while calling notifyJobStoreJobComplete method. This is causing the job to stay in BLOCKED state even if the job itself has successfully completed but quartz was unable to update its status.

#### Questions:

1. What can be the cause of the problem?
2. How to move the BLOCKED jobs into WAITING state so that the jobs can be run on their next scheduled time at least. Direct editing the QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS tables would not be a good solution, even if it works.

EDIT: To bump up the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think main problem was communication link failure by MySQL which we solved it by increasing 'wait_timeout' to 14 days and as our maintenance is scheduled in every 15 days, we restart the each of MySQL server is our DB cluster (We have Master-Master replication in place). With approach we haven't get any communication link failure after that. In fact some time we don't restart the server in every 15 days but still no error(touch wood). :)

And as far as Quartz triggers being locked in BLOCKED state, we updated the quartz to 2.1.4 which possibly has the fix for the almost same [problem](https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-179). After the quartz update, we have faced the triggers being in BLOCKED state very very less frequent.

We are still unable to find out how to get the trigger out of BLOCKED state without directly modifying the quartz tables. Whenever we face this problem, we manually remove the entry for BLOCKED trigger from the qrtz_fired_triggers table and it solves the problem. I think enterprise version of quartz may have this feature from some web UI.

Answer (score 1):

the error during notifyJobStoreJobComplete  is: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Failed to override connection auto commit/transaction isolation.
[java] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 619,082,686 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 619,082,686 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

Comment: we have validateOnCheckout as true, still connection is stale (is it possible) unless its a bug in Quartz?

Comment: Any update on this, facing this issue from last 3-4 days. can't find any solution without changing default wait_timeout

Comment: @KoushikRout I am new in quarz. Unfortunately facing similar problem . any luck with this issue??